# React Hook useCallback has missing dependencies: 'dir', 'order', 'page', 'perPage', and 'search'

Tags: reactjs

My code: looks like

```
  //GLOBAL STATE INITIALIZATION
  const page = useSelector((state) => state.users.meta.page);
  const perPage = useSelector((state) => state.users.meta.perPage);
  const order = useSelector((state) => state.users.meta.order);
  const dir = useSelector((state) => state.users.meta.dir);
  const search = useSelector((state) => state.users.meta.search);

  // FUNCTIONS
  const fetchData = useCallback(
    (
      pageNumber = page,
      pageSize = perPage,
      columnOrder = order,
      colDir = dir,
      query = search
    ) => {
      dispatch(
        listUser(pageNumber, pageSize, columnOrder, colDir, searchColArr, query)
      );
    },
    [searchColArr, dispatch]
  );
  //throwing warning above for missing dependencies


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(resetState(function () {}));
    fetchData();
  }, [dispatch, fetchData]);
```

Here, if I add the missing dependencies and replace `[searchColArr, dispatch]` with `[page, perPage, order, dir, searchColArr, search, dispatch]` then the program runs on infinite loop on. Becasuse, on `listUser` action it dispatch

```
dispatch(
  userActions.USER_LIST_SUCCESS({
    list: data.data,
    meta: data.meta,
  })
);
```

and this `USER_LIST_SUCCESS` will update redux state as:

```
USER_LIST_SUCCESS: (state, action) => {
  state.list = action.payload.list;
  state.meta = action.payload.meta;
  state.isLoading = false;
},
```

and once this meta state got updated, the `page, perPage, order, dir, search` will be updated as well and if I add these as dependencies, it fetchData again and while fetching data it update meta state and in this way infinite loops form.

What will be the best solution for this kind of situation? Or `eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` is the only option?

Update:
**listUser**

```
import user from "../../services/userService";
export const listUser =
  (page, perPage, order, dir, searchCol, search) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(
      userActions.SET_IS_LOADING({
        isLoading: true,
      })
    );
    const { data } = await user.listUser(
      page,
      perPage,
      order,
      dir,
      searchCol,
      search
    );
    dispatch(
      userActions.USER_LIST_SUCCESS({
        list: data.data,
        meta: data.meta,
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    toastify.error(error.response.data.message);
    dispatch(
      userActions.USER_LIST_FAIL({
        errors:
          error.response && error.response.data.errors
            ? error.response.data.errors
            : error.response.data,
      })
    );
  }
};
```

**user.listUser**

```
export async function listUser(
  page,
  perPage,
  order,
  dir,
  searchColArr,
  search
) {
  let searchCol = JSON.stringify(searchColArr);
  return httpClient.get(apiEndpoint, {
    params: {
      page,
      perPage,
      order,
      dir,
      searchCol,
      search,
    },
  });
}
```

**Update2**

```
const handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
  fetchData(pageNumber);
};

const handlePageLengthChange = (pageSize) => {
  fetchData(null, pageSize);
};

const handleSort = (newOrder, newDir) => {
  fetchData(null, null, newOrder, newDir);
};
```

Comment: can you show detail `listUser` function

Comment: I have updated it, could you please look and let me know.

Comment: Any help.......

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. That you will not pass `page, perPage, order, dir, search` into `listUser`. Just pass searchCol. Another param will get inside `listUser`.   You can update like this:

```
  const fetchData = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(listUser(searchColArr));
  }, [searchColArr, dispatch])

export const listUser =
  ( searchCol ) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch(
      userActions.SET_IS_LOADING({
        isLoading: true,
      })
    );
    const page = getState((state) => state.users.meta.page);
    const perPage = getState((state) => state.users.meta.perPage);
    const order = getState((state) => state.users.meta.order);
    const dir = getState((state) => state.users.meta.dir);
    const search = getState((state) => state.users.meta.search);
    const { data } = await user.listUser(
      page,
      perPage,
      order,
      dir,
      searchCol,
      search
    );
    dispatch(
      userActions.USER_LIST_SUCCESS({
        list: data.data,
        meta: data.meta,
      })
    );
  } catch (error) {
    toastify.error(error.response.data.message);
    dispatch(
      userActions.USER_LIST_FAIL({
        errors:
          error.response && error.response.data.errors
            ? error.response.data.errors
            : error.response.data,
      })
    );
  }
};
```

**Update**: If you still want to pass others params, you can check to get data.

```
listUser = (page, perPage, order, dir, searchCol, search) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const page = page || getState((state) => state.users.meta.page);
  ...
};
```

Comment: It looks one of the solution, but it might not fit to my situation, as you can see on the updated section, its possible that I could pass `page, perPage, order, size` on different scenario. So, I can't totally cut those params and retrive them directly on actions on every cases.

Comment: could you show how could I import or define `getState ` because currently, its showing not defined.